# How to capture the return value (no error code) in unix shell command?

Tags: unix

i am trying to capture the return value of simple command:

i.e:

> pwd

where can i find the relevant return value without stdout it to file?

Thanks koby

Comment: You need to specify the shell used.

Comment: i.e : awk 'NR==7' Single.log will return line 7 in Single.log

Comment: That's very nice, and what does `echo $SHELL` says ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `pwd`

for example:

```
$ setenv MY_PWD `pwd`
$ echo $MY_PWD
/my/current/path
```

Comment: When typing line : MY_PWD=$(pwd) it says "MY_PWD=: Command not found."

Comment: you have to make sure you have no spaces before the = sign: `MY_PWD=$(pwd)`

Comment: @user497159 what shell are you using? In csh for example you should use setenv to create an enviroment variable.

Comment: can you please tell me if the new command (i.e. setenv MY_PWD \`pwd\`) works ?

Comment: I'm glad it finally works ! Can you please validate my answer then ? ;)

Comment: I meant you can validate the answer by clicking the green check or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pwd`

```
ole@...:~$ echo `pwd`
/home/ole
ole@...:~$
```

Comment: how do you print those ... backtick ? :)

Comment: Do you mean how I got Stack-O to print them without converting them to "codeblock"? Escaped it with a backslash :-)

Comment: $ (and everything before it) is the shell prompt.  Ole means you should type `echo \`pwd\``.

Answer (score 1):

The first question people should be asking is... what shell are you running this in?

`$ MY_PWD=$(pwd)` will work in sh-like.

I think the  `pwd`  will call a subshell, but again, depending on the shell, the syntax to set the output value to a variable will depend on your shell.

Comment: Then you should be able to write "set variablename = \`pwd\`; echo $variablename"

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $?
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

use `$?`

Comment: This is specifically what he doesn't want